# Is there a way i can include my files and packages together in pyscript.toml?

Tags: pyscript

I am trying to write @files and @packages together in my pyscript.toml.
Separately as @files or @packages i am able to access but not @files@packages together.

I tried writing the following in my pyscript.toml

[files]
"read.txt"="read.txt"

"packages" = ["pandas"]

Comment: Unless you want to nest the `packages` key under `files`, they need to be in the opposite order, like `packages = ["pandas"]` `[files]` `"read.txt" = "read.txt"`. Not sure what “access” or the @ signs mean here though.

Comment: Just an order could make difference didn't expect.

Comment: Order doesn’t make a difference between `[section]`s, but the keys before the first `[section]` aren’t inside one. Did that solve the issue?